# How to use checks like isNullOrEmpty in Kotlin when expressions

Tags: string, kotlin, case-when, isnullorempty

Like many other programming languages, Kotlin provides checks like [isNullOrEmpty](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-empty.html), which allows simply checking variables like `myString.isNullOrEmpty()`.

Is there a way to combine such a check with a [when expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/control-flow.html#when-expression)? By default, the expression only allows explicit strings. Is something like this possible?:

```
when (myString) {
    "1" -> print("1")
    "2" -> print("1")
    myString.isNullOrEmpty() -> print("null or empty") //This is what I am looking for
    else -> print("None of them")
}
```

Comment: The issue is that your `when` is expecting strings, but isNullOrEmpty returns `Boolean`... so you have to decide which `when` you want to test against or come up with your own function that returns the string or null if it's blank or empty instead of boolean or check for null and `""` in your when.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can eliminate argument of `when` like this:

```kotlin
when {
    myString == "1" -> print("1")
    myString == "2" -> print("2")
    myString.isNullOrEmpty() -> print("null or empty")
    else -> print("None of them")
}
```

Or explicitly say "null or empty string":

```
when (myString) {
    "1" -> print("1")
    "2" -> print("2")
    null, "" -> print("null or empty")
    else -> print("None of them")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

#### UPDATE

I hadn't tested this, but then realized the logic is inverted :)

So you want to return null when it's NOT null or Empty (it sounds confusing) but this is because you want to return the exact string (source) *if* it's null or empty, so the when statement matches (remember you're comparing strings) and so it goes into the "is null or empty" branch.

Here's an updated version:

```
fun CharSequence?.nullOrEmpty(): CharSequence? = 
    if (isNullOrBlank().not()) null else this
```

A bit confusing, so you're gonna have to find a nicer name :)

Alternatively, you can make a regular function like:

```
fun nullOrEmpty(source: String?): String? =
        if (source.isNullOrEmpty().not()) null else source
```

And then call it like:

```
        when (source) {
            "1" -> print("1")
            "2" -> print("2")
            nullOrEmpty(source) -> print("It's null or empty")
            else -> print("none")
        }
```

Again, the naming should be improved (good luck, naming is hard!) :)

Consider `isNullOrBlank()` too, since that one will prevent strings like `"   "` too, whereas empty only checks `length == 0`

#### OLD ANSWER.

Vadik's answer is correct; if you want a "function", you can extend one:

```
 fun irrelevant(source: String?) {
        when (source) {
            "1" -> print("1")
            "2" -> print("1")
            source.nullOrEmpty() -> print("null or empty")
            else -> print("none")
        }
    }

fun CharSequence?.nullOrEmpty(): CharSequence? = if (isNullOrEmpty()) null else this
```

Comment: I'm wrong this doesn't work for `""`. Let me try something.

Comment: This is extremely confusing. I think an extension defined as `String.nullIfBlank()` would be more appropriate, and I would understand better as a reader if the call was made in the `when` subject: `when(source.nullIfBlank()) { ... }`. That being said, since OP didn't include blank strings in the check, I would just go for a branch with `null, "" -> ...`.

Comment: It is indeed, I probably wouldn't bother with anything like this, but it's what the OP wanted. /shrug

Comment: Fair enough. Although I believe very few people could read the resulting code in less than 10s (which is already pretty generous for this piece of logic IMO), so I'd rather argue with OP that it's probably not the right thing to want :D

Comment: I would probably do what Vadik did (`null, ""` or filter it beforehand.